# How do you have an associate array element point to a normal array (and add to it)

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I want to create an associate array, where the first element points to a (normal) of elements. The array would look something like is:

[Jim] => (23, 18, 20)

[Mary] => (57, 19, 26, 67, 103)

This example has two elements, and each of those has its first element indexed by a 'name' (associativley).

The second element of each of these two entries is an array. These are essentially ways to access other data structures and these elements can have a variable number of elements.

I am really struggling to get the syntax right.

Do I declare the overall array as (say, as it is in a class)

```
protected $names = [];
```

... then when I come to add a new name, do I add to the array as:

```
array_push($this->authors[$givenName], array());
```

[this seems to work]

... but how do I add elements to the array that [$givenName] now points to?

I have been struggling for a couple of days and can't find the right syntax.

Any help appreciated.

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that your syntax is correct. Instead, try the following:

```
//checking if we've initialized the data for $givenName; if not, we initialize the array before inserting
if(!isset($this->authors[$givenName])) {
    $this->authors[$givenName] = array();
}

//insert a value into $givenName's array
array_push($this->authors[$givenName], $some_val);

//result is $this->authors = array($givenName => array($some_val))
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I was trying something like this but never arrived at that solution.